# Passing data from simple NSView to SwiftUI View

Tags: swift, macos, uikit, swiftui

I'm making a macOS app with SwiftUI. I have a struct conforming to `NSViewRepresentable`, whose purpose is to detect the key code of whichever key was pressed. I want to pass the `event.keyCode` back to SwiftUI and save it into an environment object so I can use the key code elsewhere in my app.

I know I am supposed to use SwiftUI coordinators, but all tutorials and Stack Overflow questions I can find use ready-made classes such as `UIPageControl` or `UISearchBar` that have pre-configured delegates. I'm not sure what to do when using a simple custom `NSView`.  Can somebody explain how to pass the data from the `NSViewRepresentable` struct into my `@EnvironmentObject` when using a custom `NSView`?

```
struct KeyboardEvent: NSViewRepresentable {

    class KeyView: NSView {
        override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { true }
        override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
            print("\(event.keyCode)")
        }
    }

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = KeyView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.window?.makeFirstResponder(view)
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var input: KeyboardInput     // save the keyCode here
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(input.keyCode)
            KeyboardEvent()
        }
    }
}
```

Right now it prints the key code normally to the Xcode console, so the detection works fine.

Comment: btw, I know this question is SUPER simple, but I'm very new to app development in general and I've been stuck on this for days now, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution (with some replicated parts). Tested with Xcode 11.4 / macOS 10.15.4

```
class KeyboardInput: ObservableObject {
    @Published var keyCode: UInt16 = 0
}

struct KeyboardEvent: NSViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var keyStorage: UInt16          // << here !!
    init(into storage: Binding<UInt16>) {
        _keyStorage = storage
    }

    class KeyView: NSView {
        var owner: KeyboardEvent?   // << view holder

        override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { true }
        override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
            print("\(event.keyCode)")
            owner?.keyStorage = event.keyCode
        }
    }

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = KeyView()
        view.owner = self           // << inject
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            view.window?.makeFirstResponder(view)
        }
        return view
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) {
    }

}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var input: KeyboardInput     // save the keyCode here
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Code: \(input.keyCode)")
            KeyboardEvent(into: $input.keyCode) // << binding !!!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I copy this exact code into a project and I get:

 SwiftUI/EnvironmentObject.swift:70: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type KeyboardInput found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for KeyboardInput may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

Comment: hey man, no need to be rude. Just letting you know the answer is either incorrect, incomplete, or something has changed. Maybe there's even a bug in newer versions of xcode...