# Passing data from simple NSView to SwiftUI View: Ie event.keyCode case

Tags: macos, swiftui

When I try the solution (please look at [Passing data from simple NSView to SwiftUI View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832689/passing-data-from-simple-nsview-to-swiftui-view)) with OSX 10.15.6 and XCode Version 11.6, I receive the following error message from the system, any idea? Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type KeyboardInput found. A View.environmentObject(:) for KeyboardInput may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file SwiftUI, line 0 2020-08-07 11:05:36.189871+0200 pickit[8642:182114] Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type KeyboardInput found. A View.environmentObject(:) for KeyboardInput may be missing as an ancestor of this view.: file SwiftUI, line 0

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

This

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var input: KeyboardInput
...
```

requires that environment object be provided in place of view creation (in that case in `SceneDelegate`), like

```
ContentView().environmentObject(KeyboardInput())
```

(the same in preview provided if used)

Comment: I'm using SwiftUI. In that case I can't find any SceneDelegate. So I don't understand what to do. I'm very rookie, please could you be more precise, maybe with a snippet? Thanks for helping!

Comment: SceneDelegate is used in SwiftUI with UIKit Life-Cycle (all projects with SwiftUI 1.0 support). If you started with Xcode 12 and SwiftUI Life-Cycle then you should find swift file with WindowGroup have ContentView() and add environmentObject there... Don't fear to be curious - search ))

Comment: Ooops, Sorry, I have not indicate that i'm trying to code for a MacOS App.

Comment: It does not much matter - SwiftUI almost completely crossplatform.